# Heat Transfer. Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, conventions

Everything I read says that "heat 'flows' from 'hot' to 'cold'" or "thermal energy is transferred from 'high' to 'low'" So my question is: **why isn't the 'transfer' or 'flow' considered equal/simultaneous?**

By this I mean if we put two objects together one 'hot' and one 'cold' the 'cold' one heats up at the exact same time as the 'hot' one cools down.  So if it's like a collision of two billiard balls the fast ball slows down because it hit the slow ball and the slow ball speeds up at the moment of impact.

So is it just convention that we say the fast one transferred speed to the slow one rather than saying the slow one reduced the speed of the fast one? I somewhat get thermodynamics, but is it a matter of convention. I understand the law says "such and such" but is that just the way we phrased the law or is there more to it?

I think I'm not making any sense.

Comment: What is your specific question? this was somehow a complaining rather than a question. Can you write the specific question part in `**bold**`?

Comment: It's just more convenient and intuitive to say "energy flows from A to B" than "absence of energy flows from B to A". Is that your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Everything I read says that "heat 'flows' from 'hot' to 'cold'" or "thermal energy is **transferred** from 'high' to 'low''"

emphasis mine

Transfer is to move from one place to another.  When we talk about heat transfer it is known that the transfer involves a heat loss and a heat gain between the transfer media.

The sign convention is that gaining heat (going from cold to hot for example) is positive heat transfer for the object gaining the heat.  This convention matches the convention for other forms of energy where energy into the system is positive.  The hot object does get colder when this occurs.

Answer (score 1):

> So is it just convention that we say the fast one transferred speed to the slow one rather than saying the slow one reduced the speed of the fast one?

No, convention has nothing to do with it, it's probability.

There is more chance that a particle moving faster than a particle moving slowly will end up in the cold part of the system. Sure, it can go the other way, on a particle level, but the overwhelming probability is that the faster particles will end up in the cooler section, eventually thermal equilibrium will be established.

The more you get into your course, the more this point will come up.

Answer (score 0):

JMac and Countto10 have already answered your question. If a third answer is being added now, then it is because your question is unclear. To me it seems that you desire a symmetry in description of heat transfer. When two balls collide you can say that they exchanged momentum, and you cannot, in any absolute sense, designate one as donor and the other as receiver. Both balls are on equal footing as regards momentum transfer. However in heat exchange between two bodies at different temperatures, there *is* a donor in the absolute sense, viz. the hotter body. So you are probably asking if the description of heat transfer can be modified such that both bodies can be treated on equal footing as regards heat transfer.

This is not always possible, but in some circumstances you may entertain this way of thinking about heat transfer. In radiative heat transfer between two bodies at temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$, you can say that each of them gives off radiation energy proportional to $T_1^4$ and $T_2^4$, and the net $T_1^4-T_2^4$ determines the magnitude and direction of heat flow. Laws of thermodynamics are then interpreted as statements regarding net heat transfer between bodies. Even in simple conduction and convective heat transfer, where heat transfer is proportional to $T_1-T_2$, this way of thinking about it is alright. In fact whenever dependence of heat transfer on temperature of the two bodies can be represented as proportional to $f(T_1)-f(T_2)$, where $f$ is any arbitrary monotonic-increasing function of temperature, you can always think this way. However if heat transfer depends on $T_1$ and $T_2$ in a more complicated way, say it is proportional to the product $T_1T_2$ or to $(T_1-T_2)^\alpha$, then such an interpretation breaks down.

As far as I am aware no law requires that dependence of heat transfer on temperature be always of the form proportional to $f(T_1)-f(T_2)$. Therefore not relying on this hypothesis, thermodynamics explicitly states that heat flows from hot body to cold body.